# Why doesn't ngModel update the model when typing a-z or A-Z characters? This problem happened when I used Chrome in MacOS

Tags: angularjs

I stopped using AngularJs for a while. Yesterday I just run some basic code just to not forget the syntax then the problem happened. The `user.name` didn't update when I type a-z and A-Z characters. It only updated when I clicked somewhere in the browser or typed numbers or special characters.  This problem only happened in Chrome on MacOs( Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)), when I used Safari or used Chrome on Windows(my MacBook runs dual-boot) it didn't happen.

The code I run is the last example in  [this Angular ngModel doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

app.js

```
angular.module('getterSetterExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var _name = 'Brian';
  $scope.user = {
    name: function(newName) {
     // Note that newName can be undefined for two reasons:
     // 1. Because it is called as a getter and thus called with no arguments
     // 2. Because the property should actually be set to undefined. This happens e.g. if the
     //    input is invalid
     return arguments.length ? (_name = newName) : _name;
    }
  };
}]);
```

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="userForm">
    <label>Name:
      <input type="text" name="userName"
             ng-model="user.name"
             ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" />
    </label>
  </form>
  <pre>user.name = <span ng-bind="user.name()"></span></pre>
</div>
```

[Please check the error screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6aLo.png). 
Could anyone explain this to me? Did I miss something?

Comment: What happens when you change `ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"` to `ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true, updateOn: 'input', debounce: {input: 0} }"` ?

Comment: It still happens. Even if I run another examples, no getterSetter, no ng-model-option, just the normal 2 way-binding to the model, it all still happens

Comment: So if the exact same example works on different OS, or different browser on the same OS then it sound like a bug. I would consider submitting an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues) about this. But make sure you're using the latest version of angularJS because it might be already fixed of you're using an older angularjs

Comment: Yes I was using the latest version of AngularJs. I tried 2 version master-snapshot and 1.7.x-snapshot and it all happens